# CAB overflow menu custom style

Tags: android, contextual-action-bar

In my application I am showing a contextual action bar and because I don't have room for all the actions, some of them are accessed under the overflow menu button. Now I want to style the overflow menu and change its background. My theme inherits from Theme.AppCompat, and I have these styles defined:

```
<item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu</item>
<item name="android:listPopupWindowStyle">@style/PopupMenu</item>
<item name="android:dropDownListViewStyle">@style/DropDownListView</item>

<style name="PopupMenu" parent="Widget.AppCompat.PopupMenu">
    <!--<item name="android:popupBackground">@color/dark_color</item>-->
    <item name="android:textColor">?android:textColorPrimary</item>
    <item name="android:dropDownSelector">?popupItemBackground</item>
</style>

<style name="DropDownListView" parent="Widget.AppCompat.ListView.DropDown">
    <item name="android:listSelector">?popupItemBackground</item>
    <item name="android:divider">@null</item>
    <item name="android:dividerHeight">0dp</item>
</style>
```

The other menus in my application (overflow menus in action bar and other) are styled, but the contextual action bar's overflow menu is not. What should I do?

Comment: Have you made any progress on this? I found `actionModePopupWindowStyle` in `platform_frameworks_base/core/res/res/values/themes.xml` and `Widget.PopupWindow` in `platform_frameworks_base/core/res/res/values/styles.xml` but overriding it in my styles doesn't seem to have an effect.

Comment: I haven't found a solution yet...

Comment: @JDJ I found a solution. See my answer..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally have a solution. It seems that you need to add this to your theme:

```
<item name="actionBarPopupTheme">@style/ThemeOverlay.My</item>
```

Where:

```
<style name="ThemeOverlay.My" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat">
    <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/my_theme_background</item>
</style>
```

The colorBackground attribute can take any color value that you like and with this you have the contextual action button's overflow menu styled.

Answer (score 2):

To change the overflow menu background, you'll need to override attribute `actionOverflowMenuStyle`:

```
<!-- add to your parent style -->
<item name="actionOverflowMenuStyle">@style/LStyled.PopupMenu.OverflowMenu</item>

<style name="LStyled.PopupMenu.OverflowMenu" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.PopupMenu.Overflow">
    <!-- 'overlapAnchor' changes position of the popup -->
    <!-- true - popup will be shown over the overflow button -->
    <!-- false - popup will be shown below the overflow button -->
    <item name="overlapAnchor">false</item>
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@drawable/bg_cab_popup</item>
</style>
```

Drawable `bg_cab_popup` can be any kind of drawable. But, using a 9-patch makes sense.

If you need to change anything other than the background, please leave me a comment.

Comment: I was trying your solution with entering a colour value for popupBackground and did not worked as expected. The outcome was some kind of doubled, wrong looking background for the overflow menu, but it did change it. When I try with a drawable resource, it works. But then I need to imitate the background of the other menus in my application, which have the default form (I just change the colour). Can I just change the colour here also somehow or should I look for the android resource they use for menu's backgrounds? If that is the case where can I find it? Thx

Comment: @Sandra I haven't tried passing a color value in place of a drawable. The problem could be that `ColorDrawable` (this is what a color value is finally converted to) does not have intrinsic width and height. I use Photoshop for most image processing. The obvious benefit is that you can have completely custom themes. Something like this: [Overflow menu Bg using a 9patch](http://pho.to/8jgBs).

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume you're using the latest (21.x.x) appcompat-v7 library and have adpoted the new `Toolbar` widget. To achieve what you want you don't modify your main app theme (except for the text selection action mode) but apply a style to the `Toolbar` element in your layout (`style="@style/Widget.YourApp.Toolbar"`). The style definition may look similar to this:

```
<style name="Widget.YourApp.Toolbar" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar">
  <item name="android:background">#111</item>
  <item name="android:elevation" tools:ignore="NewApi">8dp</item>
  <item name="theme">@style/ThemeOverlay.YourApp.ActionBar</item>
  <item name="popupTheme">@style/ThemeOverlay.YourApp</item>
</style>
```

For what you're trying to achieve the `popupTheme` is the most important attribute. It points to another style definition which will describe the look of the toolbar's popup menu.

```
<style name="ThemeOverlay.YourApp" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat">
  <item name="android:colorBackground">#f00</item>
  <item name="android:textColor">#ff0</item>
</style>
```

**Important:** Notice that you'll be using this as a *theme* not a *style*. When you apply a style the attributes are set **only to the one layout element** you specify it at. When you apply a theme the attributes **propagate to all its children**. That's why when using themes you never override the `background` (which would cause overdraw and undesired looks) in favor of more specific attributes like `windowBackground` or `colorBackground` (which apply only to the relevant top element).

To make this example complete I'll include a toolbar theme as well:

```
<style name="ThemeOverlay.YourApp.ActionBar" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar">
  <!-- these color action bar title and subtitle -->
  <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#00f</item>
  <item name="android:textColorSecondary">#0ff</item>
  <!-- this colors the icons (apply manual tinting for non-appcompat icons programmatically) -->
  <item name="colorControlNormal">#0f0</item>
  <!-- bug in the library - the overflow icon on Lollipop will now respect the above -->
  <item name="android:colorControlNormal" tools:ignore="NewApi">?colorControlNormal</item>
  <!-- these color the text of action items -->
  <item name="actionMenuTextColor">?colorControlNormal</item>
</style>
```

**Remember:** When using custom text colors, use a selector and define the disabled color as well (doubly so if you're using the color on a button or in a menu).

### EDIT

The above solution is said not to apply to contextual action bar or action mode popup. I found out that it's controlled by the following attribute defined on the activity theme:

```
<item name="actionModePopupWindowStyle">?attr/popupWindowStyle</item>
```

The default value points to `@style/Widget.PopupMenu` which is defined as follows:

```
<style name="Widget.PopupWindow">
    <item name="popupBackground">@drawable/editbox_dropdown_background_dark</item>
    <item name="popupAnimationStyle">@style/Animation.PopupWindow</item>
</style>
```

Create a custom style based on `Widget.PopupWindow` and point to it from `actionModePopupWindowStyle`.

Comment: The solution you are suggesting works fine for the toolbar and its overflow menu, but does not work for the overflow menu in the CAB. I tried it, and the contextual action bar's menu is still not styled...

Comment: Please see the updated answer. The action mode requires "old school" styling.

Comment: Thank for your help so far, but I still can't get it to work. I implemented actionModePopupWindowStyle in my activity's theme, and pointed it to my custom style that looks something like this:     <style name="My" parent="Widget.AppCompat.PopupWindow">
        <item name="android:popupBackground">@color/light_theme_background</item>
    </style>. This still does not provide styling for the contextual overflow menu:((

Comment: Try putting the `actionModePopupWindowStyle` to the `Toolbar` instead of the `Activity`.