# Change background color of ToolbarItems

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

How do I change the background color and text of ToolbarItems? The default color is black and I would like to change how to do it?

[Click here to see the example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kLBHS.png)

```
<ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
    <ToolbarItem Order="Secondary" Icon="morevert.png" Text="Atualizar" Command="{Binding Atualizar}"/>
    <ToolbarItem Order="Secondary" Text="Ajuda" Command="{Binding Ajuda}"/>
    <ToolbarItem Order="Secondary" Text="Sair" Command="{Binding Sair}"/>
</ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
```

Comment: Start in [their help forums](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/22017/how-to-change-navigation-bar-color)

Comment: If the toolbaritem color; I guest that it can help you... https://stackoverflow.com/a/28979152/10868460

Answer (score 1):

Try it in your NavigationPage:

```
        BarBackgroundColor = Color.Black;
        BarTextColor = Color.White;
```

**EDITED**

I am sorry. You can apply a style to your Android app within the android project.
For an easy way to generate your style take a look at the [Android Style Generator](http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator/). You must create a style and use it in your app. How use - read this [article](http://blog.masterdevs.com/xf-day-6/).

Comment: That did not help me! It is changing the color of the ContentPage.ToolbarItems and this is not what I want, that just change the color of the items, as it is in the image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kLBHS.png

Comment: Click on this link that will display what I want: http://i.stack.imgur.com/kLBHS.png  I want to change the black background color and the text also and put another